# Python: How do you format a string % number with str.format()

Tags: python, string

How can I format a string like this

```
"%01.2f" % pr"%01.2f" % some_number
```

but using the str.format() style? I'm used to this:

```
'{0} {1}'.format(somevalue1, somevalue2)
```

Is there a way to use that function style vs the old % style, and still achieve this decimal formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be like `{0:01.2f}`, I believe.  See http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax.

**Edit**: added in your zero-padding.

Comment: Your format string is 01.2f, and originally I had 1.2f, so I changed it to match yours.

Comment: oh, What does zero padding do? I copied that code from somewhere.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't seem to work though. The above formatting outputs in this format: 9.55, rather than 09.55